# One Event Handler for many Actions

Tags: events, javafx, handler, eventhandler

Im struggling to understand how to reduce my code so that 5 TextField inputs are all directed to one Event Handler class.  It all works, there is just so much repetition.  Any advice is appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
    TextField studentIdTf = new TextField("Student ID");
    studentIdTf.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter unique Student ID"));
    studentIdTf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int studentIdTfInt = Integer.parseInt(studentIdTf.getText()); 
                System.out.println(studentIdTfInt);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            }
        }
    });  

    TextField quizTf = new TextField("Quiz");
    quizTf.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter Quiz score"));
    quizTf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int quizTfInt = Integer.parseInt(quizTf.getText()); 
                System.out.println(quizTfInt);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            }
        }
    }); 

    TextField asg1Tf = new TextField("Assignment 1");
    asg1Tf.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter Assignment 1 score"));
    asg1Tf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int asg1TfInt = Integer.parseInt(asg1Tf.getText()); 
                System.out.println(asg1TfInt);
                if (asg1TfInt < 0) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                if (asg1TfInt > 100) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ex2) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number within the range 0 - 100");
            }
        }
    }); 

    TextField asg2Tf = new TextField("Assignment 2");
    asg2Tf.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter Assignment 2 score"));
    asg2Tf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int asg2TfInt = Integer.parseInt(asg2Tf.getText()); 
                System.out.println(asg2TfInt);
                if (asg2TfInt < 0) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                if (asg2TfInt > 100) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ex2) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number within the range 0 - 100");
            }
        }
    });

    TextField examTf = new TextField("Final Exam");
    examTf.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter Exam score"));
    examTf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int examTfInt = Integer.parseInt(examTf.getText()); 
                System.out.println(examTfInt);
                if (examTfInt < 0) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                if (examTfInt > 100) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ex2) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number within the range 0 - 100");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define a method:

```
private TextField createTextField(String text, String tooltip) {
    TextField textField = new TextField(text);
    textField.setTooltip(new Tooltip(tooltip));
    textField.setOnAction(event -> {
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        }
    });
    return textField ;
}
```

and then you can just do

```
TextField studentIdTf = createTextField("Student ID", "Enter Unique Student ID");
TextField quizTf = createTextField("Quiz", "Enter Quiz Score");
// etc etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great success.